# C# Excel number format as Brazilian currency

Tags: c#, excel, number-formatting

I'm trying to format a column of a data sheet to Brazilian currency format like so:

```
excelWorksheet.Range["S1", "S" + linhas].NumberFormat = "R$ #.###,00"
```

But it's formating like this: "RR$ 3500,00".

The value is 3500 and I want like this: R$ 3.500,00

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you use that format as a custom format in Excel directly (outside of C#)?

Comment: It works. 

I want to do the same as if I put currency in format.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what the data looks like in Excel? (both when you apply that format in Excel directly, and from your app)

Comment: No, here we use dot for thousand separator: R$ 3.500,00

Comment: I can't, actually I'm in my company network and the proxy blocks upload of images.

In excel it is like: 3500

Comment: Shouldn't you use "$ #,###.00"? Off the top of my head "." means decimal separator and "," means thousands separator. It should be replaced by the actual separators from the regional settings. Also "$" is the currency which would be set to R$ in your case. That's why you're getting a double R.

Comment: Great! It worked!

Is there any way to format when the value is 0 (zero)? It´s setting like this: R$ ,00

Comment: I achived it with "$ #,###0.00". Thanks a lot guys!

@H.deJonge write as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you use "$ #,##0.00"?

The "." indicates the decimal separator and "," is thousands separator. Excel should replace them with the actual separators from the regional settings. Also "$" is the currency which would be set to R$ in your case. That's why you're getting a double R.

See [Custom Number Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.95).aspx) for more information.